# Run spreadsheet function from google form script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I want to call a user spreadsheet function from the google form submission to update some information in the spreadsheet.

All scripts are on the same google drive.

Is there a way to do that ?

Code in my google form:

```
function updateSheet() {
  spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('daedaeddea');
  spreadsheet.myFunction();
}

function onOpen() {
 var form = FormApp.openById('deadeadaedae');
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('updateSheet')
     .forForm(form)
     .onFormSubmit()
     .create();
}
```

Comment: Spreadsheets with attached forms have an `onFormSubmit` trigger which can be used to run a script. Call it from the spreadsheet, not the form.

Comment: In my case, it is not a spreadsheet with attached forms. The spreadsheet is independant from the forms.

Comment: What do you mean by "a user spreadsheet function"?

Comment: A macro script (function in google script) defined in a spreadsheet script project.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely connect Google Forms with Spreadsheets. There's a sample in [Quickstart: Managing Responses for Google Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms) on how to do this using the onFormSubmit trigger.

Here's a snippet:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var user = {name: e.namedValues['Name'][0], email: e.namedValues['Email'][0]};

  // Grab the session data again so that we can match it to the user's choices.
  var response = [];
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Conference Setup')
     .getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    var session = values[i];
    var title = session[0];
    var day = session[1].toLocaleDateString();
    var time = session[2].toLocaleTimeString();
    var timeslot = time + ' ' + day;

    // For every selection in the response, find the matching timeslot and title
    // in the spreadsheet and add the session data to the response array.
    if (e.namedValues[timeslot] && e.namedValues[timeslot] == title) {
      response.push(session);
    }
  }
  sendInvites_(user, response);
  sendDoc_(user, response);
}
```

Comment: It seems that we can't call a user spreadsheet script from a google forms script. You have to rewrite code that manipulate the spreadsheet in the google forms script.